# Получение координат без GPS

Tags: arduino, position, gps, позиционирование

Как я могу получить координаты(траекторию) на Arduino  без использования GPS?

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Какая точность нужна и где это будет применяться?

Comment: and without wi-fi

Comment: Нужна большая точность .Это для робота,который анализирует трубы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попытаться учитывать все управляющие команды на перемещение и исходя из них вычислять текущее положение относительно точки старта.

По этому принципу работает танковое навигационное оборудование.

Comment: А как с погрешностью бороться в случае подъема или спуска под уклон. И ведь еще на реальную дальность перемещения как правило влияет сила сопротивления среды. Например: трение, преграды, пробуксовки, вязкость среды, встречные и попутные потоки(жидкости, воздух), скольжение. Есть может какая-то метода для оценки растояния визуально? Может триангуляция относительно стабильных источников излучения?

Comment: Как учитывать все управляющие команды на перемещение.В трубе может быть что угодна.